# Nginx load another file at home page

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx configuration that's working, but I have a weird situation. The `/index.html` file isn't what I want to load at `/` or `/index.html`. At those locations I want to load `/home/index.html`. I'm not sure what the best strategy is to configure this. This is the pseudo-config I have so far.

```
location [/ or /index.html] {
  load /home/index.html instead, respond 200 not with a redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for this. Something like:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /home/index.html;
}
```

Note: This will give you /home/index.html for every bad address too, maybe not what you want.

Edit: Or just symlink /index.html to /home/index.html.